# Change aggfunc of pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as `df` which I want to turn into a pivot_table. Now one of the column (named as `"series"`) of the dataframe contains only string values.
so I have to change the `aggfunc` as

```
aggfunc={"series":lambda x: ''.join(x)}
```

But if I do so all the other 8 columns that has numeric data is lost in the pivot table and the pivot table only contains the `"series"` columns.
To prevent this I have to pass `aggfunc` for every columns individual like

```
aggfunc={"series":lambda x: ''.join(x),"cost":numpy.mean,......}
```

But `numpy.mean` is the deafult argument for `aggfunc`. So what I want is to change the `aggfunc` only for one column and for the rest of the columns I want to left it as default. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: IMO it won't work until you generate a full dictionary like this: `aggfunc={"series":lambda x: ''.join(x),"cost":'mean','col_Z':'mean'}` - this one can be generated by a function which should "know" what columns should be excluded: - all columns that have been specified for `index` and `columns` parameters

Comment: Well, thats what I am doing here. But I am looking for a way to pass agaggfunc to a single column without affecting the others because I have total 11 column and only bothering about this whole aggfunc things only for one column.

Comment: I guess you would have to change `pivot_table` function - so you can do  [pull request](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/contributing.html)